# How to log and utilize usage patterns in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, analytics

I have a rails app and want to log how often a user triggers certain events. I want to use it not just for analytics but to use it as one of the core features in the app (such as ranking and displaying the info).

For example, I could log how often a user comes back to the app and use that information to rank users.

Is there any ruby gem that makes it easier to do something like this?
I didn't think using 3rd party analytics engine was the way to go because this is a core feature to the product. However I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is very broad so no matter what you select,  you will have to customize it.

I think the merit gem is a good start.   You can configure the gem to mark the sessions controller action to gain points and then rank the users using the points.

Some might say that this is not the intended purpose of the gem but I think it depends on what you think the app main purpose.

Check out the gem here:   https://github.com/tute/merit

Good luck!